# Using contains via LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I will preface with I am incredibly new to LINQ. I am trying to do a simple `contains` via my LINQ query. Below is my query:

```
myList.AddRange(oGal.AddressEntries.Cast<Outlook.AddressEntry>().Select(
     x => new ListDetails
          {
             Id = val,
             Name = x.Name
          }).Take(400));
```

Right now I am using `Top 400`, but would actually only like to add objects to my list that contain `#`. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at the [Where method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
myList.AddRange(oGal.AddressEntries.Cast<Outlook.AddressEntry>()
    .Where(i=>i.Name.Contains("#"))
    .Select(
       x => new ListDetails
             {
                Id = val,
                Name = x.Name
             }).Take(400));
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. All of these do the "deed", but @Jonathan answer seems to be most efficient "fastest" for my specific case.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just want to check where the name contains # like you said

```
myList.AddRange(oGal.AddressEntries.Cast<Outlook.AddressEntry>()
      .Where( x => x.Name.Contains("#").Select(
          x => new ListDetails
          {
              Id = val,
              Name = x.Name
          })));
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the collection, this may be less efficient, as it will return all records and then filter them after creating the new objects, instead of filtering them on the get, and only creating a subset of objects.

Comment: `x.Name.Contains("#").Select` won't compile

Comment: Ah old javascript tendencies I fixed it

Answer (score 4):

This should do it, use contains in where method:

```
myList.AddRange(oGal.AddressEntries.Cast<Outlook.AddressEntry>()
      .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("#"))
      .Select(
           x => new ListDetails
                 {
                    Id = val,
                    Name = x.Name
                 }));
```

Comment: I dont think he needs the take 400 OP stated 'Right now I am using Top 400, but would actually only like to add objects to my list that contain #'

Comment: Now that look more like my answer :p